# Hashset memory overhead

Tags: c#, memory, hashset

In `C#` program I have two `Queues` of `longs`, `26M` elements together and four `HashSets` of `longs`, `50M` elements together. So my containers are storing `75M` `longs` which gives `600MB` of data. Memory usage of program is `3GB`.

Why these containers need so much memory? What is memory complexity of `HashSet`? Even if all structures doubles theirs capacity, it will give `1.2GB`, not `3GB`.

EDIT:
Yes, I didn't mean complexity. How much additional memory `HashSet` needs to store `long`? Simple binary heap doesn't need any additional memory. Is there any alternative for `HashSet` if I need to lower memory usage or I need to implement one myself?

Comment: The memory complexity should be O(n).  Perhaps you meant to ask about the storage overhead of HashSet?  (And sorry, I don't know the answer to that question.)

Comment: "Is there any alternative for `HashSet`" Depends, what do you need the collection to do? Do you need to be able to add more items to the collection? Do those items added need to be checked for duplication? There may be lighter weight options, but you need to tell us the requirements.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain this program is checking states (longs) to determine if there are winning or losing. So when I process one state I'm checking connected states if there are winning or losing (using `Contains`) and then sometimes I'm adding processed state to winning or losing states.

Comment: How are you measuring the memory being used? Just because task manager says you are using 3gb of memory doesn't mean that your application is currently using all of that memory.  Depending on how much memory the system has and what is currently running that number can vary widely.

Comment: Is there a problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I did the math and `HashSet<long>` would take about 24 bytes per long, and when expanding capacity it doubles the current capacity and rounds up to the next prime. So 3GB is not that unreasonable.

Comment: You can call [HashSet<T>.TrimExcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468758(v=vs.110).aspx) when you are done adding elements. But whether that returns memory (hard drive space) to the OS depends on how the garbage collector plays "nice".

Comment: It's interesting that the team/guy behind ClrMD considered the memory use of HashSet<ulong> '*extremely* memory inefficient' (see comment in code sample on https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnetsamples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime/CLRMD/docs/WalkingTheHeap.md). In their samples they provide a (use-case specific) alternative (see ObjectSet in https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnetsamples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime/CLRMD/GCRoot/Program.cs).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Overview

HashSet has 12 bytes of overhead per slot (which can contain an item or be empty).  This overhead is 150% larger than the data size in the case of storing longs.

HashSet also holds empty slots for new data and the number of items in your example (~12.5 million items per HashSet) leads to about 66% higher memory usage just due to empty slots.

If you need O(1) confirmation of existence in the set then a HashSet is perhaps the best you can do.  If you know something special about your data (e.g. that it contains "runs" of hundreds of items in a row) then you might be able to come up with a more clever way to represent this that requires less memory.  Without knowing more about the data it's hard to make suggestions about that.

### Test Program

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var q = new Queue<long>();
        var hs = new []
        {
            new HashSet<long>(),
            new HashSet<long>(),
            new HashSet<long>(),
            new HashSet<long>()
        };

        for (long i = 0; i < 25000000; ++i)
        {
            q.Enqueue(i);

            if (i < 12500000)
            {
                foreach (var h in hs)
                {
                    h.Add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

### HashSet Implementation - Mono

Slot Allocation Strategy - Doubles the size of the table on each allocation.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Collections.Generic/HashSet.cs

### HashSet Implementation - MSFT

Slot Allocation Strategy - Allocates using primes.  This can lead to substantial amounts of empty space, but reduces the number of times that the table must be reallocated and rehashed.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs

### Memory Usage - General Sizing - Mono Implementation

- Initial Size: 10 Slots
- Fill Factor: 90% Full Triggers Resize
- Resize Factor: Doubles size when fill factor reached

### Memory Usage - Per Slot - Both Implementations

- Table: 1 x 4 byte int per slot = 4 bytes / slot
- Links: 2 x 4 byte ints per slot = 8 bytes / slot
- Slots: 1 x (sizeof T) bytes = 8 bytes / slot (for T = long)
- Total: 20 bytes / slot

### Slots Used in Example - Mono

The example has 12.5 million items in each HashSet.

slots = 10 * 2 ^ ceiling(log2(items / 10))

log2(12,500,000 /10) ~= 20.5

slots ~= 21 million

### Memory Used in Example - Computed - Mono

Queue: 25 million longs * 8 bytes / long = 200 MB

Each HashSet: 21 million slots * 20 bytes / slot = 420 MB

All HashSets: 1.68 GB

Total: 1.88 GB (+ empty space in the Large Object Heaps)

### Memory Used in Example - Observed with Son of Strike - MSFT Implementation

3.5 GB memory in .Net heaps

400 MB of Int32 arrays (used by HashSet, not for our data storage)

2.5 GB of HashSet Slot objects

Note: MSFT's Slot object is 8 bytes plus the size of the data (8 bytes in this case), for 16 bytes total.  2.5 GB of Slot objects is 156 million Slots, for storing only 50 million items.

### dumpheap -stat

```
!dumpheap -stat
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00007ffb549af228        1           24 System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib]]
[snip]
00007ffb53e80bd8      159         6926 System.String
00007ffb53e81250       27        36360 System.Object[]
00000042ed0a8a30       22     48276686      Free
00007ffb53f066f0        3    402653256 System.Int64[]
00007ffb53e83768       14    431963036 System.Int32[]
00007ffaf5e17e88        5   2591773968 System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1+Slot[[System.Int64, mscorlib]][]
Total 343 objects
```

### eeheap -gc

```
!eeheap -gc
Number of GC Heaps: 1
generation 0 starts at 0x00000042800472f8
generation 1 starts at 0x0000004280001018
generation 2 starts at 0x0000004280001000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000004280000000  0000004280001000  000000428004b310  0x4a310(303888)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000004290001000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000004290000000  0000004290001000  0000004290009728  0x8728(34600)
00000042dc000000  00000042dc001000  00000042e7717e70  0xb716e70(191983216)
000000433e6e0000  000000433e6e1000  000000434f9835b0  0x112a25b0(287974832)
00000043526e0000  00000043526e1000  000000435a6e1038  0x8000038(134217784)
000000435e6e0000  000000435e6e1000  0000004380c25c00  0x22544c00(575949824)
00000043826e0000  00000043826e1000  000000438826c788  0x5b8b788(95991688)
000000438a6e0000  000000438a6e1000  00000043acc25c00  0x22544c00(575949824)
00000043ae6e0000  00000043ae6e1000  00000043b426c788  0x5b8b788(95991688)
00000043b66e0000  00000043b66e1000  00000043d8c25c00  0x22544c00(575949824)
00000043da6e0000  00000043da6e1000  00000043e026c788  0x5b8b788(95991688)
00000043e26e0000  00000043e26e1000  0000004404c25c00  0x22544c00(575949824)
0000004298000000  0000004298001000  00000042a8001038  0x10000038(268435512)
Total Size:              Size: 0xcf1c1560 (3474724192) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:            Size: 0xcf1c1560 (3474724192) bytes.
```

Comment: You linked the HashSet implementation for mono, [here is the implementation from Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs).

Comment: Thanks Scott - Didn't find that link quickly enough, so I went with Mono :)  Looks like MSFT's implementation is probably going to have more empty slots because it does resizing by picking the next largest prime.  Indeed, the MSFT Slot contains two ints and a T, or 16 bytes per Slot, which gives 162 million slots in this example, for storing just 50 million items (using 223% additional storage beyond the actual data).

Comment: Microsoft updated their reference source website back in February to add that new web interface, a lot of people still don't know about it.

Comment: Sadly @huntharo didn't specify/link to the actual versions of `HashSet<T>` that they used at the time they wrote this answer, so the figures presented may very well no longer be valid. For example, Mono no longer has their own HashSet; they use Microsoft's version from the reference source, so behaviour should be identical.

Comment: If you want that version of the Hashset, just go look at the git history for the git link I provided and pull it from the date I submitted my answer. But it's probably really not that interesting if Mono has, in fact, ditched their implementation in favor of MSFT's. In that case, just look at the analysis for their implementation (assuming you are using a version of Mono recent enough for that change to apply to you).